# Determining parent ethnicity

Tags: dna, ancestry.com

My father and I both took Ancestry.com DNA tests. His came back 100% European Jewish, while mine came back 37% Italian and 63% European Jewish.

Does this most likely mean my mom is 26% European Jewish? Is there a more technical explaination as to why my results came out the way they did? All of her grandparents were Italian immigrants (with Italian last names).

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy StackExchange! Not being expert in Jewish genetic genealogy, I'll post this as a comment, rather than an answer. Yes, the obvious implication is that your mother has a "Jewish" grandparent. I put that in quotes because ethnicity estimates are just that (estimates), and reflect comparisons with contemporary populations. Most such are geographical, which Jewish obviously is not. So, learning the vendor's criteria for classification as Jewish might be enlightening.